# Create a new value based on summing specific columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col2 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col3 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col4 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to create a new vector (outside of the dataframe) `var` that will state `1` if the sum of `col3` and `col4` is >= 4 and 0 otherwise. How can I do this? I tried using `sum` within an `ifelse` statement but it seems to produce a `character` output.

Any leads? Thanks!

Comment: You can do `vec1 <- with(dat, +((col3 + col4) >= 4))` or `vec1 <- +(rowSums(dat[3:4]) >=4)`

Comment: @akrun thanks! What if there are `NA`s that I want to ignore in col3 and col4 in the addition process?

Comment: then `rowSums` will be better as it have `na.rm` argument.  I posted a solution with that option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are `NA`s as well, then use `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
vec1 <- as.integer(rowSums(dat[3:4], na.rm = TRUE) >= 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a more general way, you can also go the apply route with all sorts of further logic included in the defined function should such be needed...

```
apply(dat,1,FUN=function (x) {as.integer(sum(x[3:4], na.rm=TRUE)>= 4)})
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, we can use `mutate` to create a new column (`var`) using `rowSums` and the condition of whether the sum of `col3` and `col4` is greater than or equal to 4. Here, I use `+` to convert from logical to 0 or 1. Then, we can use `pull` to get the vector for `var`.

```
library(tidyverse)

var <- dat %>% 
  mutate(var = +(rowSums(select(., c(col3:col4)), na.rm = TRUE) >= 4)) %>% 
  pull(var)
```

**Output**

```
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

Or another option is to use `sum` with `c_across` for each row:

```
var <- dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(var = +(sum(c_across(col3:col4), na.rm = TRUE) >= 4)) %>% 
  pull(var)
```